# Smashing the Aravos/Jews without Torah or Mitzvos

Tags: lulav-etrog-arba-minim, hoshana-rabbah

According to the understanding that the aravos symbolize the Jews without Torah or Mitzvos ([Vayikra Rabba 30:12](https://www.sefaria.org/Vayikra_Rabbah.30.12?lang=bi) מָה עֲרָבָה זוֹ אֵין בָּהּ טַעַם וְאֵין בָּהּ רֵיחַ, כָּךְ הֵם יִשְׂרָאֵל יֵשׁ בָּהֶם בְּנֵי אָדָם שֶׁאֵין בָּהֶם לֹא תּוֹרָה וְלֹא מַעֲשִׂים טוֹבִים), why do we bang the aravos on the ground on Hoshana Rabba?

Comment: FWIW, I don't think any of the four typs of Jews would appreciate being picked up and waved around either.

Comment: Do you know why we bang them according to any other understanding? If not why ask only about this one? Why do you think this one would be different?

Comment: @Salmononius2 Check out Bamidbar 8:11.

Comment: @DoubleAA Very fair point - I wanted to keep the question more narrow as well as understand if there is a lesson from banging the aravos in how to work with Jews without torah/mitzvos

Comment: @NJM Have you ever looked at the Malshinut blessing in the Amidah prayer?

Comment: There are 4 different types of avodah mentioned in that blessing from the most extreme to the most gentle. What is appropriate varies according to who you are dealing with. The lesson with the Aravot is to engage with an emphasis on the physical/material dimension. Initially, the action is the primary thing. And like with everything associated with Sukkot, “Serve HaShem with joy.” Like it emphasizes v’samachta b’Chagecha!

Comment: @YaacovDeane Thank you for the insight - I saw something similar in Rav Hirsch's 2nd volume of collective writings, though I'm not sure how that point explains smashing the aravos in the understanding of this particular Midrash

Comment: Excellent shiur from Rav Breitovitz https://torahdownloads.com/shiur-1024633.html explains much about the custom and its meanings.